# I am getting this error "media type unrecognized" when I upload this image?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am getting this error ("Media type unrecognized.") after uploading these kinds of images. Uploading this image directly to twitter works fine but not through the API. This is the image:

**Image:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
images = []
for x in user_tweet_images_list: # AWS S3 image urls
    media_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
        delete=False,
        suffix=get_image_extension(x.tweet_image.url)
    )
    media_file.write(x.tweet_image.read())
    images.append(media_file.name)

media_ids = [api.media_upload(i).media_id_string for i in images]
post_tweet = api.update_status(status=user_tweet.tweet_message, media_ids=media_ids)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This error is actually a `TweepError` originating from Twitter's API. The likely issue is that you're uploading an empty file because you haven't flushed the data to the temporary file, e.g. with `media_file.flush()`.

<s>This is likely due to [a known Tweepy issue](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1060) and will probably be fixed when v3.9 is released with [a fix](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1086).</s>

<s>In the meantime,</s> Depending on what `get_image_extension` does, you might need to add a dot (`.`):

> [NamedTemporaryFile] does not put a dot between the file name and the suffix; if you need one, put it at the beginning of suffix.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: Thanks, Harmon, that function already returning the suffix with a dot (.). I also tried it with a hardcoded value but not worked.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I didn't realize that your error is actually a `TweepError` originating from Twitter's API. The likely issue is that you're uploading an empty file because you haven't flushed the data to the temporary file, e.g. with `media_file.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks @Harmon758, It's working now. Edit you answer I will accept it.